# primary key violation even though record doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I have created a trigger the code is below.

I'm slightly confused though as running an update query on my table I get an error message 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint'. However where I query the table the value I'm updating doesn't exist in the table? directory is the primary key column.

```
update myTable
set directory = 'madeup2'
where directory = 'madeup'
```

So the query above is what is causing the violation of primary key constraint.

But I do the select query below and there is no directory in my table called madeup2 - no records are returned.

```
select * from myTable where directory = 'madeup2'
```

Is this something to do with my trigger?

```
create trigger trDefaultPath on mytable
instead of insert, update, delete
as
begin
declare @defCountIns int
declare @retVal int
declare @permission bit

select @defCountIns = count(userName) from inserted where userName = 'Default'
select @retVal = count(HostName) from UserHostName where HostName = HOST_NAME()

-- workout permissions
if @retVal = 0 and @defCountIns > 0
    set @permission = 0
else
    set @permission = 1

begin                                           
    if @permission = 1
        begin
            update mytable
            set directory = inserted.directory,
            pathNumber = inserted.pathNumber,
            userName = inserted.userName
            from inserted;
        end
    else
        begin
            update mytable
            set directory = inserted.directory,
            pathNumber = inserted.pathNumber,
            userName = inserted.userName
            from inserted
            where inserted.username <> 'Default';
            print 'Do not have permission to update directories'
        end
end         
end
```

**Update**

Thanks to the comments which pointed out that the update statements in my trigger are missing a where clause.

One thing I don't understand though is I executed a update query with a where clause. In the inserted table though I will just have new 'directory' value so how do I create the where clause?

Is it simply a case of using the deleted table - so delete the records in that table from mytable and then add the records from inserted table to mytable?

Comment: Your `UPDATE` statements will update the **entire** table - not just those rows that have been  modified. That's *usually* not what you want - you'll need to add a `JOIN` between your `Inserted` pseudo table and the actual underlying data table that you want to update.

Comment: oh of course! Your right thanks - I do not want to update the entire table. If you put your comment as an answer I'll make it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` statements will update the entire table - not just those rows that have been modified. That's *usually* not what you want.

You'll need to add a `JOIN` between your `Inserted` pseudo table and the actual underlying data table that you want to update.

```
 if @permission = 1
 begin
     update mytable
     set directory = inserted.directory,
         pathNumber = inserted.pathNumber,
         userName = inserted.userName
     from inserted i
     inner join mytable on i.ID = mytable.ID;  -- or whatever column is your PK
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your trigger, your first UPDATE doesn't have a WHERE clause.  And the second one has a WHERE clause that doesn't reference the table being updated.

That means it's going to try to update every row in the table with the same values from the inserted table.

Also your trigger isn't coded to handle inserts/updates that affect more than one row.

Comment: how do I adjust my trigger so than it can handle more than one row being affected?

Comment: By joining the inserted table to the "mytable" table on the appropriate column.   Since Directory is your PK, you should probably join on that.   But I'm really not clear on why you want your trigger to handle inserts, updates and deletes, when the code only does an update.

Comment: I removed the code that handles the insert and deletes to make my example easier to read

Answer (score 0):

This update statement has no `where` clause. It will attempt to update the `directory` field for every record in the table. This will cause a primary key violation whenever the table has more than one record in it.

```
        update mytable
        set directory = inserted.directory,
        pathNumber = inserted.pathNumber,
        userName = inserted.userName
        from inserted;
```